# Airtable Formula remove everything until "["

Tags: formula, airtable

In Airtable I have a field with the Type "Formula" and with a input like this "[XXX] Lorem Ipsum"

Now what I want to do, is that if "[XXX]" exists, that it removes this Block and the next " "

This should be the outcome:
"[XXX] Lorem Ipsum" => "Lorem Ipsum"
"Test Test ] Lorem Ipsum" => "Test Test ] Lorem Ipsum" (Only remove if it has a open-bracket)

I already tried some things but it doesn't work.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`REGEX_REPLACE()`](https://support.airtable.com/hc/en-us/articles/203255215-Formula-Field-Reference#regex_functions) function to do this:

```
REGEX_REPLACE({field},"\\[.+\\] ","")
```

This will take any run of text enclosed in square brackets and followed by a space, and remove it.

```
Input                     =>  Output
-----                         ------
[XXX] Lorem Ipsum         =>  Lorem Ipsum
[XXX]Lorem Ipsum          =>  [XXX]Lorem Ipsum
Test Test ] Lorem Ipsum   =>  Test Test ] Lorem Ipsum
[Test Test ] Lorem Ipsum  =>  Lorem Ipsum
```

Answer (score -1):

Airtable has a function called substitute() that may work.

Try:

```
substitute( {field}, '[XXX] ', '')
```

Comment: Hi David, take a closer look at the third paragraph in the question.

Comment: I see the error of my ways, I'll look closer next time.  :)